# Need to find the name of the current file in excel addin

Tags: vsto, excel-addins

I have an excel addin for 2003 excel.
This add in adds a menu command to the excel menu.

what my requirement is that, when I click on this menu command I need to send the name of the current file to a different process... how do I obtain this information..

Please help me 
thanks
sandeep

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're in the addin, try

```
string currentWorkbookFileName = this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

(if not I think there is a global, something like `Globals.Application` or `Globals.ThisAddin.Application` instead)

Comment: Yup, you got it. ThisAddin.Application is the ticket.